# EC2 instance not show web site

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have instance with such security rules

[image: security groups]

and I connect by ssh to my instance and install nginx

```
sudo yum install nginx
```

then run service

```
sudo service nginx start
```

and status is running

[image: nginx status]

but when i go to this address

[image: ip address]

connection is refused

more info:

[image]

Comment: if you run curl localhost:80 from within the server does it respond correctly?

Comment: yes, it return nginx page

Comment: Is it possible the browser trying to upgrade the connection to https?  If it isn't I'd take a look at the firewall settings on the server next.

Comment: Yes, the problem was in https in browser

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of googling I found the answer... By default if I go to the public ip address, chrome use https connection. And it was a problem. When I manually typed http - page opened.